# How to redirect a link to another link 2 in magento

Tags: htaccess, 301-redirect, redirection

I have a blog page on this URL: http://159.203.70.155/index.php/blog/ and another page that have the same contents but different URL  as this http://159.203.70.155/index.php/education-center.

Now i want to redirect /blog page to the new LINk /education-center

I have tried it with HTACCESS but it is not working please check if i am doing anything wrong:

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

      ############################################
      ## enable rewrites

       Options +FollowSymLinks
       RewriteEngine on

      ############################################
      ## you can put here your magento root folder
      ## path relative to web root

      #RewriteBase /magento/
      Redirect permanent /blog http://159.203.70.155/index.php/education-center
      </IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Redirect 301 /blog http://159.203.70.155/index.php/education-center` in `htaccess` file.

Think it's better to use outside `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` condition because it's not a url rewrite but just a 301 redirect.

Comment: Its not worked i have put it at the top of htaccess file as you said to use it out of rewrite condition
 Pleae check:
http://159.203.70.155/index.php/blog/